# Javascript - Add extra global params to all request

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

How to handle all request (submit, refresh page, ...) and append a global params ex:

> windowsID=xxxxxxx

I want to send windowsID to server for identify the current window tab..

for all ajax i use:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  data: {
    windowsID: "xxxxx"
  }
});
```

Comment: Tip: you should try to avoid calls to `$.ajax/get/post` in many locations of your code. What if you'd like to cache responses based on query and url? You'd have to go through all your code and find `$.get/post/ajax` instances. Instead you should wrap it in a function (for example makeRequest) so when you need to implement something new globally you know where to do this and need to do this in only one place.

Comment: yep..you're absolutely right but the project was not developed by me ... I have the onerous task of adding support for multitab

Comment: for this reason I have to add widowsID

Comment: You have any idea for help me??

Comment: Not really, You're worried that user can change something so you can try saving window id on the server but tabs share same session so when window loads you need to make a xhr to the server maybe with special header variable or post body telling the server what tab this is. Then when that comes back you can update content with server response based on tab id.

Comment: ..mm make a XHR on before all unload ...no good idea for me...I have made a sistem for lock a localStorage when tab1 set your wid...and sync all tab ....if the tab2 try to set the "wid" key it will find the block and wait until the tab1 has released it

Comment: but I wanted to see if there is a simpler and more reliable solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    var updateQueryStringParam = function (key, value) {

    var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join(''),
        urlQueryString = document.location.search,
        newParam = key + '=' + value,
        params = '?' + newParam;

    // If the "search" string exists, then build params from it
    if (urlQueryString) {
        var updateRegex = new RegExp('([\?&])' + key + '[^&]*');
        var removeRegex = new RegExp('([\?&])' + key + '=[^&;]+[&;]?');

        if( typeof value == 'undefined' || value == null || value == '' ) { // Remove param if value is empty
            params = urlQueryString.replace(removeRegex, "$1");
            params = params.replace( /[&;]$/, "" );

        } else if (urlQueryString.match(updateRegex) !== null) { // If param exists already, update it
            params = urlQueryString.replace(updateRegex, "$1" + newParam);

        } else { // Otherwise, add it to end of query string
            params = urlQueryString + '&' + newParam;
        }
    }

    // no parameter was set so we don't need the question mark
    params = params == '?' ? '' : params;

    window.history.replaceState({}, "", baseUrl + params);
};
updateQueryStringParam("wid","xxxxx");
console.log( window.location.href );  // whatever your current location href is

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have created this code for add param...but the url is editable for client user and its possible that is deleted manualy